# subshells and parallel processing

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

I was looking at http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html, where they mention that subshells can be used for parallelizing tasks.  They then give the example:

> ```
> (cat list1 list2 list3 | sort | uniq > list123) &
> (cat list4 list5 list6 | sort | uniq > list456) &
> # Merges and sorts both sets of lists simultaneously.
> # Running in background ensures parallel execution.
> #
> # Same effect as
> #   cat list1 list2 list3 | sort | uniq > list123 &
> #   cat list4 list5 list6 | sort | uniq > list456 &
> ```

```
wait   # Don't execute the next command until subshells finish.

diff list123 list456
```

Are the first two commands not going to finish in roughly the same time as the second two commands? I had thought that the last two commands will also execute in parallel, and with some `sleep` loops, I was unable to create a situation where they differed.  How do the last two commands differ from the first two?  If they don't differ, then why are subshells mentioned as a method of parallelization when the same could be done with putting the processes in the background?

Comment: I don't think there's any significant difference. That's why the comment says that they have the same effect.

Comment: This is one reason to avoid the ABS; the example is incredibly contrived and doesn't actually require a subshell, let alone a pipeline: `sort -u list1 list2 list3 > list123 &`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, both:

```
c1 | c2 &  # where c1 and c2 are arbitrary commands
```

and:

```
(c1 | c2) &
```

use subshells, as does:

```
c1 | c2
```

without the `&`.  The reason is that, in general, a pipeline requires creating a subshell.

(There are some very specific cases where some shells, including bash, can avoid creating a subshell: for instance, `prog | while read ...` does not create a separate subshell for the `while` loop in bash, provided you set `lastpipe` (`shopt -s lastpipe`) *and* job control is not active.  It always does create a subshell in some other shells.  This can be seen by observing the values of variables set by or within the `while` loop.  But when the `c2` command is not a shell built-in, the shell has to make a sub-shell internally in order to hook up the pipe.)

Comment: `bash` requires the `lastpipe` option to be set to avoid creating a subshell the `while` loop.

Comment: @chepner: oops, yes, I thought it was on by default, but it seems to be off by default.

Comment: Doesn't `c1 | c2 &` mean send c2 to background? That is, c1 and c2 are both started in their own subshells, but c1 needs to finish dumping its output to the pipe before `c1 | c2 &` as a whole returns so that bash can go to the next statement?

Comment: @ffledgling: no, the pipeline "binds tighter" than the background `&`, so this "means" `{ c1 | c2; } &` (to write it in a form without an explicit sub-shell). To force the `&` to bind only to `c2` you must write `c1 | { c2 & }`.

Comment: Oh, operator precedence.

Answer (score 1):

It'll be the same for piping / oring / anding  commands.

But if your parallelization requires more than one line, you'll need a subshell, ie

```
(echo a ; sleep 2 ;  echo b) &
```

is not equal to

```
echo a; sleep 2; echo b &
```

Also, subshells need to instantiate separate environments, so it has an (usually trivial) execution penalty

Answer (score 1):

lets have a job script and a manager script like below. Then the manager will run 2 jobs at the same time and wait until both jobs are done -- see output below.

*job.sh* (print the argument and wait for 0.1 sec -- loop 10 times)

```
i=0
while [ $i -lt 10 ]
do
  echo "${i}: job $1"
  i=$[$i+1]
  sleep 0.1
done
```

manager.sh (start 2 parallel jobs and wait for both jobs to finish)

```
echo "start"

./job.sh 1 &
./job.sh 2 &

wait

echo "done"
```

will give the following output:

```
./manager.sh 
start
0: job 1
0: job 2
1: job 1
1: job 2
2: job 1
2: job 2
3: job 1
3: job 2
4: job 1
4: job 2
5: job 1
5: job 2
6: job 1
6: job 2
7: job 1
7: job 2
8: job 1
8: job 2
9: job 1
9: job 2
done
```

Which kind of proves your thesis that both process have almost same time for running.